# Azure Function requires hosts.json logging for Serilog to work in log stream

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, serilog

I have this code setup to configure Serilog:

```
    public static IFunctionsHostBuilder AddLogger(this IFunctionsHostBuilder builder, string applicationName)
    {
        builder.Services.SetupLogging(applicationName);
        return  builder;
    }
    
    
    public static void SetupLogging(this IServiceCollection services, string applicationName)
    {
        var logger = CreateLogger(applicationName);
        services.AddLogging(lb =>
        {
            lb.AddSerilog(logger);
        });
    }

    public static Logger CreateLogger(string applicationName)
    {
        
        var instrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
        
        return new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)  
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", applicationName)
            .Enrich.WithCorrelationIdHeader(Constants.CorrelationIdHeader)
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration(instrumentationKey), TelemetryConverter.Traces)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
```

I then have `ILogger<MyClass>` injected into my function class and I do `logger.LogInformation("test")` and all is fine.

However, I have noticed I required `hosts.json` to contain the below for logs to appear in Azure Portal log stream. Oddly, App Insights contains the data whether hosts.json contains the below or not. It seems like the console logs don't adhere to the Serilog configuration and rely on hosts.json.

Can anyone explain this and get it working without the hosts.json needing to be populated

```
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just configure in your *SetupLogging* method

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(sp => new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger, true));

builder.Services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true));
```